# Audio not playing in Ipad but is playing in laptop

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, audio

The audio is being played into the laptop and PCs but it is not playing in ipad. I tried in different ipads but it is not playing the audio.

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.type='audio/mpeg';
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', '/*file url over here*/');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);
        audioElement.play();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have found the answer. The $.get(); should be jQuery.get();.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have made a srcset, that covers all supported codecs on all devices / browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_browsers

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The $.get(); should be jQuery.get();